# What are the Conditions to Change Thread Priority while Running Thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

With This Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyThread testThread = new MyThread();

    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());

    testThread.start();

    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
    testThread.setPriority(7);
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
}
```

I get an Output where setPriority works as expected - the output is 5-5-7.
But when commenting out the top getPriority as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    MyThread testThread = new MyThread();

    //System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());

    testThread.start();

    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
    testThread.setPriority(7);
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
}
```

The Priority doesn't change at all, I get an Output of 5-5. Why is that and what determines if the Thread Priority gets changed or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the priority of a thread that has already run, it has no effect. For example:

```
    MyThread testThread = new MyThread();
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
    testThread.start();
    // sleep for 1 second, making sure that testThread is done
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));
    // reports false
    System.out.println(testThread.isAlive());
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());

    testThread.setPriority(8);
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
```

Running this will reveal that `testThread.setPriority(8);` has no effect, the thread is not alive anymore.

If we go to your example and add two statements:

```
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
    System.out.println(testThread.isAlive());
    testThread.setPriority(7);
    System.out.println(testThread.isAlive());
    System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());
```

and run the code *with* and *without* that `System.out.println(testThread.getPriority());` - you will see that in one case (when that line is commented), the thread is not `alive` anymore (unlike when that line is *not* commented). Thus the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! How is the `getPriority()` keeping the thread alive for the extra amount of time?

Comment: @Beo it's just an artifact of how the scheduling of threads happen, just remember that even the behavior that we both talk here is not guarantee. You can add a simple `testThread.start(); LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));...` and notice that the code now changes...